# Unable to see the IBInspectable custom properties in Storyboard of the custom view class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have created custom UIView class with IBDesignable method enable in it. 
Inside the class, I have added few IBInspectable properties looks something like this,

**Swift 4.0 - Snippet:**

```
@IBDesignable
class SegmentView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth = 0.0 {
            didSet{
                layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
            }
        }

        @IBInspectable var borderColor = UIColor.clear {
            didSet{
                layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            }
        } 
}
```

Whenever I am using this class in StoryBoard for UIView element, I am unable to view above declared IBInspectable properties in storyboard -> View -> View Property Tab, for reference please check below-attached screenshot.

[image]

**Issue:** In the above segment view header, there are no IBInspectable properties available.

Can someone help me to resolve my above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try restarting xcode?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the variable type, like:

```
@IBDesignable
class SegmentView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your variable with following it will solve your problem.

```
        @IBInspectable
        public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0{
                didSet{
                        self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
                }
        }

        @IBInspectable
        public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
                didSet{
                        self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.cgColor
                }

        }
```